# Sharepoint 2013 - Token Lifetime FBA

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2013, fba

Context of my situation is:

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise running on premises with FBA connected to a AD database.

I would like to set a maximum lifetime for login to 90 minutes. What I mean by that is, anyone that has logged in will have to log in again after 90 minutes, regardless of active or inactive.

I have looked through stackoverflow and couldn't find anything as specific as that.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can change the token by SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig, via PowerShell.

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15) 
$sts.Update()
```

Might need an IIS-reset.

Comment: Rasmus, thanks for your reply. I have a question, does that works for Form Based Authentication? If so, then is my code below correct? 

$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (90)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (1)
$sts.Update()